# ArcGIS CutFill raster output to polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, cut-fill

I've got a raster with the cut fill tool, its attribute table shows volume information which I'd like to pass to a polygon overlapping the raster.

The polygon  was originally used to clip a raster file so as to extract all depressions of a terrain, later the cut fill tool was used to obtain material volume to fill these depressions. Every thing shows wonderful on the raster cut&fill output but I haven't been able to pass the volume field back to the polygon file as a new field

I've tried to use raster to polygon, extract values to point, some statistical tools, etc, etc with no success at all

Comment: Assuming you have a spatial analyst license, or you wouldn't be able to do cut/fill, you can use Zonal Statistics https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics/009z000000w7000000/ with in zone data as your polygons, value raster as your cut/fill raster and a statistic type of SUM to add the volume required to each polygon; you may have already tried this tool, a very common mistake is to overlook the zone field, FID/OID should do to summarize on a *per polygon* basis, which is what I assume you want otherwise there is a risk of coalescing the polygon values.

Comment: I already tried this, the output is just a new raster, with some statistical data depending on the chosen function.

Comment: The raster containing the cut&fill data uses some value for the cell height which isn't the volume. The volume and area are associated attributes to the raster I don't know how to extract

Comment: It's the height (depth) of the sink from the fill level, the calculation is *cell width X cell height X depth (raster sink value)*.. you could create a volume raster with the cut/fill tool using the square metre value for each cell in the z_factor or from what you have perform a multiplication by the square metre size for each cell; note that this only works in projected coordinates, if you are using geographic coordinates the size of each cell is not constant in metres so the calculation would yield only approximate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

1. Replace polygons by points using "Feature to point"
2. "Extract multi values to points" chose as raster the cut&fill. This will add the FID of the raster to the points.
3. Join by attributes the cut&fill with the last points
4. Edit to remove unnecessary columns and join to the polygon